# Why can't I save a Jupyter notebook as a .ipynb?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Every time I click download as .ipynb it saves as .json. Even deleting the extension .json, it remains as a .json document. I am on a Mac if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter Notebooks use the `.ipynb` file extension, but they are simply JSON documents. If you are seeing a JSON document created, then it is saving correctly.

The file extension will simply identify the specific type of JSON, and signal what application should open it.

I'm not sure why your files are being created with `.json` instead of a `.ipynb`, but changing the file extension is correct.